# How to divorce remotely?

Tags: divorce

I am a UK citizen, who has been married to an American woman for about 18 months. We got married in the UK, lived together for about 3 months and later on she moved back to the US because of job opportunity. I stayed at home and later on we decided to break up. However we remained married on the paper and had an agreement when it comes to a divorce, none of us is going to have any property aquired since the moment of separation. So basicaly we have been separated for 10 months and now she assumed filing a divorce with an online company, and I hesitate whether it would be legit on the territory of the UK if we got divorced remotely like that, so I wonder how the process of a divorce could be accomplished, if she is not willing to come to the UK.

Answer (score 3):

The divorce under Florida, USA, law, will be recognised in the UK and have legal effect.

> Under the **Family Law Act 1986** an overseas divorce obtained by means of
> judicial or other proceedings is recognised in the UK only if:
>
> - it is effective under the law of the country in which it was    obtained; and
> - at the relevant date (that is, the date on which proceedings were begun), **either** party was *either habitually resident or domiciled
>   in that country* or *was a national of that country*.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/overseas-divorces-set13/overseas-divorces-set13

You may need to take additional steps in the UK as a Florida divorce certificate may not be familiar to organisations who need to be told of your divorce.

> Obtaining recognition of your foreign divorce in the UK can be
> extremely complex and we strongly advise anyone who is unsure to
> contact a legal professional in the UK to ensure their overseas
> divorce is valid and there could be no repercussions down the line.

https://www.nelsonslaw.co.uk/foreign-divorce-valid-england/

Comment: @FloydRiddle  I'll point out that the FLA phrase cited above ("...habitually resident or domiciled in that country...") is **not** necessarily the same as "qualifies for family law dissolution under the law of that country." The petitioner might qualify to file (after living there for, say, six months) but still **not** be found "habitually resident or domiciled" as required by the FLA. The OP should consult a UK solicitor before proceeding.